# How to fix an if, elseif, and else statement causing an HTTP 500 error?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an if, elseif statement causing an HTTP 500 Error. I would really appreciate the help figuring such a simple problem out. Thank You!

I have tried changing my conditions, deleting the elseif (which worked), alternating between elseif and else if. I have searched Google, and the answer is nowhere to be found.

```php
<?php 
if($row7Count == 0) {
    // This code works fine
} elseif($editAgent != null) {
    // This code causes HTTP 500 error
} else {
    //This code works fine
}
```

Expected results is to execute any code within elseif statement, even a simple echo 'testing'; does not work.

> Actual results = HTTP 500 Error

Comment: For clarification `$row7Count = 1;` and `$editAgent = 2;`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<?php 
if($row7Count == 0) {
    // This code works fine
} else if(!is_null($editAgent)) {
    echo "test";
} else {
    //This code works fine
}
```

Comment: That worked. And I'll do it that way. But while applying that "fix", I found an extra braces. I looked over this code 100 times and never once noticed an extra brace. Thanks.

Comment: probably the main thing was elseif to else if :)